# regsvr32.exe threading issues (WaitForMultipleObjects() and SetEvent())

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, dll, regsvr32

I'm having some issues with regsvr32.exe hanging during an installation. A DLL, let's call it common.dll, is registered as part of the installation process using regsvr32.exe. Common.dll utilises another DLL, utility.dll.

Part of utility.dll contains logging functionality. This logging functionality uses a static 'Timer' object to periodically check log file sizes and splitting accordingly. The Timer object incorporates it's own thread which it uses to fire the timer. The timer object inside the logger is a static, so it is used across multiple logger instances which use static ofstreams to point to the same file.

The timer has two events, a timer (created using CreateWaitableTimer()) and a standard synchronisation event (CreateEvent()) for triggering thread shutdown. The thread is started in the constructor (_beginthreadex()). Inside the thread function there is a WaitForMultipleObjects() call waiting on both the timer and the shutdown event. The Wait...() is INFINITE, and the thread function returns when the shutdown event is set (SetEvent()).

(The above is provided as background, no part of it can be changed as part of the solution, and all DLL files, the logger and the timer are working properly).

The issue arises during regsvr32.exe running. It loads up common.dll, which loads up utility.dll, which initialises the static timer thread object. The thread is started properly, and it reaches the WaitForMultipleObjects() call inside the thread function. As soon as registration completes (almost instantly), the timer destructor is called. The destructor calls SetEvent() on the shutdown event, **but WaitForMultipleObjects() never returns.** As part of trying to figure out this issue I've put a WaitForSingleObject() call immediately after the SetEvent() call, waiting on the shutdown event. This also never returns, which leads me to believe there is an issue with the event itself. I had the following possible explanations:

1. A timing issue. The registration process is over very quickly, and as such maybe the thread is getting into a state where it isn't ready to shutdown? The thread does reach the WaitForMultipleObjects() call though, which leads me to believe this isn't the issue.
2. Utility.dll is being unloaded by regsvr32.exe. I'm not really up on how this all works, but using ProcessExplorer it looks like regsvr32.exe still has the dll loaded while it is hanging, so I don't think this is the issue.
3. A tight loop inside regsvr32.exe during shutdown. If the destruction process for regsvr32.exe is taking place in a tight loop (i.e. while(NotShutdown()) etc), maybe this isn't relinquishing any cpu time for the timer thread, which would explain the hang.

Any more thoughts on the issue? I've scoured the internet and can't find anything remotely related to this problem.

---

P.S. I know the solution to the problem is to use a static pointer and initialise the timer when it is actually needed, and that's the solution i'm going with. However i'd still like to understand **why** this is happening, as to me it seems completely ridiculous that SetEvent() would not work.

---

Output from windbg !locks command:

```
0:000> !locks

CritSec ntdll!LdrpLoaderLock+0 at 7c97e178
LockCount 2
RecursionCount 1
OwningThread d8
EntryCount 4
ContentionCount 4
*** Locked

Scanned 253 critical sections
0:000> ~*kv

. 0 Id: a40.d8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffdf000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr Args to Child 
0007e5ec 7c90df5a 7c8025db 00000764 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
0007e5f0 7c8025db 00000764 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
0007e654 7c802542 00000764 ffffffff 00000000 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xa8 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Utilityd.dll
0007e668 00a84e37 00000764 ffffffff 0007e71c kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0007e6c8 00a2e5af 0007e798 0007e754 00aa02e0 Utilityd!CThreadTimer::~CThreadTimer+0x97 [C:\xxx\ThreadTimer.cpp @ 49]
0007e71c 00aa02ae 00fe7a18 0007e740 00aa039b Utilityd!$E177+0x3f
0007e728 00aa039b 00a10000 00000000 00000000 Utilityd!_CRT_INIT+0xde [crtdll.c @ 236]
0007e740 7c90118a 00a10000 00000000 00000000 Utilityd!_DllMainCRTStartup+0xbb [crtdll.c @ 289]
0007e760 7c91e044 00aa02e0 00a10000 00000000 ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x14
0007e858 7c80ac97 00950000 00000000 0003415e ntdll!LdrUnloadDll+0x41c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0007e86c 0100214e 00950000 00000000 00020bca kernel32!FreeLibrary+0x3f (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0007ff1c 010024bf 01000000 00000000 00020bca regsvr32!wWinMain+0xad1 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0007ffc0 7c817077 00000018 00000000 7ffd4000 regsvr32!wWinMainCRTStartup+0x198 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0007fff0 00000000 01002327 00000000 78746341 kernel32!BaseProcessStart+0x23 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

   1 Id: a40.e98 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffde000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr Args to Child 
0104fe34 7c90df5a 7c91b24b 00000760 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
0104fe38 7c91b24b 00000760 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
0104fec0 7c901046 0197e178 7c913978 7c97e178 ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection+0x132 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0104fec8 7c913978 7c97e178 00000000 7ffde000 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x46 (FPO: [1,0,0])
0104ff34 7c80c136 006e0065 00560074 00fe43d8 ntdll!LdrShutdownThread+0x22 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found. Defaulted to export symbols for MSVCRTD.DLL - 
0104ff6c 1020c061 00000000 00fe43d8 0104ffb4 kernel32!ExitThread+0x3e (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0104ff7c 1020bfd8 00000000 006e0065 00560074 MSVCRTD!endthreadex+0x41
0104ffb4 7c80b729 00fe43d8 006e0065 00560074 MSVCRTD!beginthreadex+0x178
0104ffec 00000000 1020bf20 00fe43d8 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

   2 Id: a40.1708 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffdd000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr Args to Child 
0136fc0c 7c90df5a 7c91b24b 00000760 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
0136fc10 7c91b24b 00000760 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
0136fc98 7c901046 0197e178 7c91e3b5 7c97e178 ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection+0x132 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0136fca0 7c91e3b5 7c97e178 0136fd2c 00000004 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x46 (FPO: [1,0,0])
0136fd18 7c90e457 0136fd2c 7c900000 00000000 ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0xf0 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ntdll!KiUserApcDispatcher+0x7
```

Comment: Is it a manual or auto-reset event? Do you check the return value of SetEvent and GetLastError? Have you tried running under applicationverifier? It will catch stupid mistakes like passing the wrong handle (or a pointer to a handle instead of the handle itself) or invalid handles. All that said, I agree with Hans, don't start threads like that.

Comment: It's an auto-reset event, and the return value of SetEvent is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

Global destructors and constructors are called from DllMain with the loader lock held as you can see from your stack traces. The thread calling ~CThreadTimer has the loader lock and it is waiting for the event to be set. If another thread needs the loader lock to continue, it will be blocked until the event is set. If the thread that sets the event is one of the threads that needs the loader lock, you'll end up with a deadlock like this one. The loader lock is taken when dlls are loaded, when threads are created or destroyed, when dlls are unloaded, at process exit and startup, and a few other places (GetModuleHandle for example).

An easy way to create a deadlock like this is:

```
 static Foo { Foo() { HANDLE h = CreateThread(...); WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE); } g_foo;
```

That said, you implied SetEvent was indeed being called. If it indeed is, there's probably more going on.

You can use `!handle` to take a look at the event you're waiting on as well to see if you can gain some insight. Also, again I would try running with ApplicationVerifier, it may lead you to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. SetEvent() is definitely being called (and not failing).

Comment: Wait, wait. I just noticed you added an additional  WaitForSingleObject to "debug" this. You need to eliminate that, as this is an auto reset event only one of the Waits can succeed when you set the event, the other will block (unless you set the event again). This is born out by your stack traces of the hang. Only one WaitForSingleObject is blocked on the event, the SetEvent _is_ working.